# Set selected value in select list dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a select list and I'm using asp tag-helpers to create it.
I want to set the default value to the value currently set in the DB

```
<select asp-for="QualificationTypeId" id="QualificationTypeId"
      asp-items="@Model.QualificationTypes" class="ProgInfoCellWidth">                    
</select>

//@Model.QualificationType
//this is the value I want to set as the default selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default selected value into `QualificationTypeId`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the select item into the 'SelectList' and it will set it's as default selected item. like this below

```
SelectList QualificationTypes = new SelectList(QualificationTypesList, "Id", "Name", selectedQualificationType);
```

and here is the HTML DOM creation code:

```
<select asp-for="Input.QualificationTypeId" class="form-control" aria-required="true" required asp-items="@QualificationTypes">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Qualification Type</option>
</select>
```